# Middle school reader with a section of Scandinavian folk tales

Tags: story-identification

My seventh-grade English teacher kept copies of old literature textbooks in his classroom.  If we had free time, or during our individual reading times, students could read from those books if we cared to.  I paged through them a few times, and I found that one of the disused readers had a nice section of Scandinavian (or maybe Germanic more generally) myths and folk tales.  They included a version of "Sigurd the Dragon Slayer" (so titled) and "[Roi the Fool](http://www.yorku.ca/inpar/roi_eirikr.pdf)."  (It was not the William Morris translation that I linked to, however.)

I would like to find these stories again.  The textbook probably had an orange cover and monochrome interior illustrations.  The grade level was probably seven, but it could have been eighth or ninth, if my teacher had inherited the book from an earlier English teacher.  Most likely, it was printed in the late 1960s or 1970s, but if it was as old as my middle school, it could have been from any time after the Second World War.

Comment: Do you recall if it was a stand-alone book or part of a series? At age 6-7 (in 1954/5) I recall a series of slim books about various folk tales, including German (about the Nibelungs), Norwegian (about Asgard), and Welsh ones (including the Gelert legend).  Regrettably the name(s) of the author(s) are long lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for ***[Legends of the North](https://www.worldcat.org/title/legends-of-the-north/oclc/1138870)*** by Olivia Coolidge.

The covers I've seen are kind of dark, not orange.  It is illustrated (E. Sandoz, a wonderful illustrator!) Available at Amazon, etc., etc.

Contents:
Tales of the northern gods: The creation —
Hymer's caldron —
The apples of Idun —
The fenris wolf —
The hammer of Thor —
The wooing of Gerd —
Thor and the giant king —
Baldur, the beautiful —
The binding of Loki —
The last of the Volsungs: Andvari's gold —
The dragon slayer —
Fafnir's end —
The Valkyrie —
Two wives —
The murder —
The revenge —
Tales of the northern heroes: Fenia and Menia —
The unending battle —
The song of Beowulf —
Beowulf and the fire dragon —
Hagbard and Signe —
Tales from the sagas: Helga's lovers —
Roi, the fool —
Gunnar of Lithend: Hallgerda —
The theft —
The killing —
The last stand.